# tabs in multiple lines of contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, contenteditable

in the example below pls place cursor at the start of any line and press`Tab` key
this works fine
I want the same if multiple lines are selected at once and also delete one tab if `Shift+Tab` is pressed
Probably I need an array of selected lines but have no idea how to get them
Please help

```js
$('#wrap').on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 9){
        e.preventDefault();
        var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var tab = document.createTextNode("\u00a0");
        range.insertNode(tab);
        range.setStartAfter(tab);
    }
});
```

```css
.wrap{padding:0 14px 9px 14px; white-space:pre-wrap; background:orange; outline:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrap' id='wrap' contenteditable>
lorem ipsum
dolor sit
amet
</div>
```

Comment: You will want to treat each line of the selection as a row and will want to place a tab `\t` at the beginning of each line. Unless you want  to treat it as a Paragraph and you want to use Blockqupte or another styling to indent it.

Comment: @Twisty - for treating each line as a row I need an array of rows. That's the esence of question - how to get such an array. Especially if one line of text can be so long - to have multiple rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$('#wrap').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 9) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
      var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
      var tab = document.createTextNode("\t");
      if (range.collapsed) {
        range.insertNode(tab);
        range.setStartAfter(tab);
      } else {
        var content = range.toString(),
          count = (content.match(/\n/g) || []).length,
          start = 0,
          end = content.indexOf("\n");
        range.deleteContents();
        var newContent = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (var i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
          newContent.append("\t" + content.substring(start, end));
          if (i != count) {
            newContent.append("\n");
          }
          start = end + 1;
          end = content.indexOf("\n", start);
          if (end == -1) {
            end = content.length;
          }
        }
        range.insertNode(newContent);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  padding: 0 14px 9px 14px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  background: orange;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrap' id='wrap' contenteditable>
lorem ipsum
dolor sit
amet
</div>
```

Here you can see where we examine the Selection. If it is just a Single line, nothing selected or Collapsed, then we just add a Tab character (`\t`) at the front of that line. If it is multiple lines, then we need to add a Tab character to each line in the selection.

This means we need to define a Line, so from the Start of the line to the End of Line (EOL), usually Return Carriage (`\r`) and New Line (`\n`), sometimes just the New Line. If we look for the New Line character, we ensure each line can be found.

So if the selection is:

```
lorem ipsum\r\n
dolor sit
```

You want the following output:

```
\tlorem ipsum\r\n
\tdolor sit
```

First we find all the Lines and get a `count`, so that we can iterate each and append the Tab character. We collect each line, modify it, and place it into a Document Fragment for entering later. As needed, we add the New Line character back.

If you want to use an Array, then `.split("\n")` would be a good way to do this.

```js
$('#wrap').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 9) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var content = range.toString().split("\n");
    range.deleteContents();
    var newContent = document.createDocumentFragment();
    $.each(content, function(i, line) {
      newContent.append("\t" + line);
      if (i != (content.length - 1)) {
        newContent.append("\r\n");
      }
    });
    range.insertNode(newContent);
  }
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  padding: 0 14px 9px 14px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  background: orange;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrap' id='wrap' contenteditable>
lorem ipsum
dolor sit
amet
</div>
```

Comment: in one word - excellent. And clear. I didn't expect it is so huge task. Thanks a lot

Comment: @provance examples: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/897645/Replacing-selected-text-HTML-JavaScript